# Ubuntu 18 network drivers stopped working

Tags: networking, drivers, kubuntu, network-manager

My wired network connection all of a sudden stopped working on my Ubuntu 18 desktop environment where the light to my NIC stopped flashing.  Booted to live OS on usb and have internet and also tried another NIC card so it isn't HW issue. I then reinstalled network manager by downloading the .deb files and installing them manually. I still have no internet.

I did recently modify my default nameservers from my ISP to google as I was hitting a caching issue but didn't think that would affect the whole network this way. Here is a [link to my relevant](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XzBC7ybKWm/) network configs.

Can someone advise on next steps?  My googling has pointed me to network manager but given the NIC lights it seems more like a driver issue.

Don't know if it is related but the internet went out on another linux laptop of mine at the same time but is now fine. Very strange.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `dkms status`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema All items requested [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/robcxyz/8108839ec04b9388d0d28bab5c818afc).  THANK YOU!

Comment: Is this a Desktop or Server installation? It looks like you have 3 different ethernet cards, correct? Is enp39s0 your primary interface for Internet? Are you using cat 5e or cat 6 cables? Please describe your wiring from computer to router/modem. Your .yaml file is incorrect, but we'll deal with that a little later. Did you recently modify it? PS: in the future, you can just edit details into your original question, or use paste.ubuntu.com, instead of github.com.

Comment: @heynnema This is a desktop installation.  The four extra interfaces are from pcie NIC I put in to verify the problem. When I booted from a live USB, all the network interfaces worked so the extra interfaces can be disregarded. 

An important detail that just came to me was that I did modify my nameservers from my ISP to google/cloudflare. I think that is an issue you cited in the yaml but would that affect the actual NIC operation?

Will update OG question and be sure to document the answer.  Really appreciate it!

Comment: Try `sudo ifconfig enp39s0 up`.

Comment: @heynnema - Sorry, can verify the cable is cat 5e.  Also the `sudo ifconfig ..` didn't do show / do anything. I also removed the pcie network card as that is not part of this. THANKS!

Comment: Try the mods in my answer, and let's see, if by chance, it solves the problem.

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**netplan**

Change /etc/netplan/*.yaml to this:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

**NetworkManager**

Enter your DNS addresses here, max 3, automatic OFF.

[image]

Comment: First off thank you so much.  I followed the direction but when applying `sudo netplan generate` I ran into a `module not found` error for `netifaces`.  I then installed that from source and got past the `generate` but now errors with `apply` where netifaces is missing the `interfaces` attribute. Tried a couple versions of `netifaces` and seen some recent issues raised [here](https://github.com/al45tair/netifaces/issues/33#issuecomment-660506406) but other than that, I am at a loss on how to proceed.  @heynnema

Comment: @Cobman And you're using my exact .yaml file, correct? No other .yaml files, correct? I never heard of this. Where did you get source? Show me `sudo netplan --debug generate` and `sudo netplan --debug apply`. You could also try to reinstall `netplan.io` and `libnetplan0`.

Comment: @Cobman Did you finally get it working? What was wrong?